# create multi page pdf file from database whit apache PDFBoxe

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdf-generation

I am creating this small app to generate a pdf file from database I want to put every image from database BLOB format into separated pages

```
try
{
    String query="select * from papie where id='"+label.getText()+"' ";
    PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
    int i=1;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        //if(rs.getString("recto").equals(0))
        //{
        Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("photo");
        imageInputStream = imageBlob.getBinaryStream();

        doc.addPage(page[i]);

        image = new PDJpeg(doc,imageInputStream);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page[i]);

        content.drawXObject(image, 100, 555,200, 100);
        i++;
   }

   content.close();
   doc.save(fileName);

   doc.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Great. And what is your exact problem in doing so?

Comment: well first it dos not work and it give me this error java.lang.NullPointerException i have no idea where did i go wrong

Comment: What is `page[i]`? And what is the stack trace of your `NullPointerException`?